# Stack - scala implementation/performance issue

Tags: scala, data-structures

I've been looking at the [scala-lang](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html) notes on various data structures and their performance characteristics.

I have noticed that `immutable.Stack` has C (Const.) complexity for both appending and prepending, while `mutable.Stack` stack has C complexity for prepending and L (Linear) complexity for appending. This surprised me a bit.

I take it, that "appending" means just `push()` to the top of the stack. And since complexities for prepending and appending are different, does it mean that "prepending" is in fact putting something on the bottom of a Stack? Why does it perform better (C for mutable) than appending (L for mutable)? And also, how can I even prepend to the stack? I can't see any method suitable for this in the [scaladoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.4/scala/collection/mutable/Stack.html).

**EDIT.**

As @Łukasz noted in comments, you can prepend and append to the stack with `+:` and `:+` operators. The question remains though - why does prepending work better (faster) than appending to the Stack? Should I add to the bottom instead of pushing to the top?

Comment: you can prepend and append, methods are `:+` and `+:`

Comment: Good catch. I've updated the question.

Comment: `+:` should not be ever used for `Stack`, because it has a linear time, when `push` has constant time, but they do the same operation. `+:` is coming from `SeqLike` which is not aware about constant property of `Stack`'s push

Comment: Ah, ok. There is a use case (which I personally find weird) for `+:` - it always copies the structure. So if you are using mutable `Stack`, you may add element with `+:` if you want a copy with prepended element, and leave the original stack unchanged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there is a mistake in this table, or I do not get something. If you look at the implementation, `push` for both mutable and immutable `Stack` takes constant time, and `:+` for both mutable and immutable takes linear time, because `:+` is coming from `SeqLike` which does that in linear time, which is very reasonable for stack as data structure

Both mutable and immutable stacks using immutable `List` inside and using `::` operation, which is constant. `List` has it's append operation as `L`, so it's no way `Stack` can do it better

For immutable stack it is:

```
def push[B >: A](elem: B): Stack[B] = new Stack(elem :: elems)
```

And for mutable it is:

```
def push(elem: A): this.type = { elems = elem :: elems; this }
```

Also please notice that immutable `Stack` is deprecated since 2.11

P.S. I even checked the latest sources of 2.12, but it seems the code didn't change since 2.11

P.P.S. I couldn't find any insert implementation for `Stack`, and looking at the table it seems weird that only `Stack` among immutable structures can insert data, so I'd guess that `L` from that column should have been in `append` column

Comment: so to conclude - `push` == `append` and is of constant time, while `:+` works as prepend, copies and adds to bottom of the Stack and is of linear time?

Comment: @Niemand In stack `push` is prepend and `:+` is append. This is `Stack`, who is adding element in different order than `Queue`, so when `Queue` has prepend as `L` and append as `C`, `Stack` should have it vice versa. See also description of `:+` in scaladoc - it is defined there as append. http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Stack

Comment: Thanks. This was quite confusing, putting something to the top of the Stack always looked more like "appending" to me (since it is LIFO - it is strange to define last element as prepended, but that's probably FP in your face).

Comment: No, actually I don't think it's FP related. It sounds more like it is because Scala is trying to be OOP here. `push` is defined just like push, it's not append or prepend. And `:+` is called append, because this operation is actually defined on `Seq`. If you think of `Stack` as `Seq`, you need to call `:+` append, because append is the operation that is adding elements to the end.

Comment: Much better now. Thanks.